# Insert HTML doesn't work properly in Word

Tags: office-js

Trying to insert HTML in Word results in three different formats. Check out video [here](https://youtu.be/EgylQqY3JXE).

JSFiddle shows how bibliography should be formatted. Desktop Word respects some CSS, but not working properly. Online Word converts all elements to spans and ignores CSS completely.

I've created sample project to reproduce this issue [here](https://github.com/Vj3k0/content-control-bug).

Comment: thanks for reporting this, We'll take a look....

Comment: Hello Juan, any progress on the issue?

Comment: still under investigation. will update as soon as i have an answer. I wonder if in the meantime you can send the HTML without CSS usage.